# Variable number of dynamic filter conditions applied to an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to filter an array with a variable number ( 0 to three ) of filter conditions that are dynamic themselves.  For example, one filter condition is based on a name a user selects from a dropdown list on a Google Sheet. If the filter conditions aren't dynamic, such as the name being hard coded, it works.  See line below.

```
const filterFn1 = "x => x[0] === 'John Doe'";
```

I tried this, but it seems Google Apps Script doesn't recognize `new Function`

```
const filterFn1 = new Function("x => x[0] === '" + name + "'");
```

Full code:

```
function myFilter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shtDash = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const shtDB = ss.getSheetByName('Database');

  const lastDBRow = shtDB.getLastRow();
  const arrData = shtDB.getRange(2,1,lastDBRow-1,4).getValues();

  let arr = [];

  const name = shtDash.getRange('B1').getValue();
  if (name !== '') {
    const filterFn1 = "x => x[0] === '" + name + "'";
    arr.push(filterFn1);
  } 

  const category = shtDash.getRange('B2').getValue(); 
  if (category !== '') {
    const filterFn2 = "x => x[1] === '" + category + "'";
    arr.push(filterFn2);
  } 
  
  const software = shtDash.getRange('B3').getValue(); 
  if (software !== '') {
    const filterFn3 = "x => x[2] === '" + software + "'";
    arr.push(filterFn3);
  } 

  const filtered = arrData.filter(x => arr.every(f => f(x)));
}
```

Comment: `const filterFn1 = new Function("x => x[0] === '" + name + "'");` though it does not throw, of cause creates not the kind of function the OP is expecting ... if, at all, using the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) constructor then for e.g `filterFn1` like this ... `const filterFn1 = new Function("x", \`return x[0] === "${ name }";\`);`

Comment: I tried to respect your syntax in my proposal. `Eval` replaces `new function`. Of course you syntax is not usual but I tried to respect it!

Comment: `it seems Google Apps Script doesn't recognize new Function`. Doesn't matter what it seems. Tell the actual error.

Comment: @PeterSeliger your modification for `new Function` worked for me.  Thank you so much.  Everything works now.

Comment: Well done, I learned something, including how to play with the functions. So I will delete my answer. I suggest someone post this solution which is very useful!

Comment: You can also write `const filterFn1 = function(x) {return x[0] === name}`

Answer (score 5):

### Try:

```
function myFilter() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shtDash = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const shtDB = ss.getSheetByName('Database');

  let arrData = shtDB.getRange(2, 1, shtDB.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues()

  const filters = shtDash.getRange(`B1:B3`).getValues().flat()
  
  filters.forEach((filter, index) => {
    if (filter.length) arrData = arrData.filter(row => row[index] === filter)
  })

  return arrData

}
```

This will check if the `filter` value isn't blank, then will filter the `arrData` by `index` of each `filter` at the `index` of each row.

For instance, if the first filter is `X`, `arrData` will be filtered for all rows containing `X` at index `0`. If the second filter is `Y`, `arrData` will be filtered for all rows containing `Y` at index `1`, etc.

If you need more explanation or modifications, please let me know!

### Non-Index Version:

```
function myFilter() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shtDash = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const shtDB = ss.getSheetByName('Database');

  let arrData = shtDB.getRange(2, 1, shtDB.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues()

  const filters = shtDash.getRange(`B1:B3`).getValues().flat()
  
  filters.forEach(filter => {
    if (filter.length) arrData = arrData.filter(row => row.includes(filter))
  })

  return arrData

}
```

**Learn More**:

- [Array.filter(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.forEach((element, index))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you for writing a detailed explanation.  Your code works.  I decided to go with Peter Seliger's modification to the `new Function`. The added benefit is that the user entered filters don't have to match the same layout as the array I'm filtering as it would with this code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @gries If you would like to take out the hardcoding aspect, you can always try `arrData = arrData.filter(row => row.includes(filter))` as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `const filterFn1 = function(x) {return x[0] === name}`

```
function myFilter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shtDash = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const shtDB = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  const lastDBRow = shtDB.getLastRow();
  let arrData = shtDB.getRange(2,1,lastDBRow-1,4).getValues()
  let arr = [];
  const name = shtDash.getRange('B1').getValue();
  if (name !== '') {
    const filterFn1 = function(x) {return x[0] === name}
    arr.push(filterFn1);
  } 
  const category = shtDash.getRange('B2').getValue(); 
  if (category !== '') {
    const filterFn2 = function(x) {return x[1] === category}
    arr.push(filterFn2);
  } 
  const software = shtDash.getRange('B3').getValue(); 
  if (software !== '') {
    const filterFn3 = function(x) {return x[2] === software}
    arr.push(filterFn3);
  } 
  const filtered = arrData.filter(x => arr.every(f => f(x)));
  console.log(filtered)
}
```